# Why is my principled volume shader not filling the object it’s applied to?

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting, volumetrics

[image]

I have a duplicate of my walls scaled out along normals and set to display as wire, then a principled volume shader applied. But unlike in the tutorial I’m following, the volume doesn’t fill the space. It hovers as a small cube in the center. I've tried applying scale.

Comment: It looks like you're using _Eevee_... you do not show any _Volumetrics_ settings in the _Render Properties_ which are crucial in _Eevee_, so I'm quite sure that you have some settings different than the ones in the tutorial. But without knowing your settings and which tutorial you are talking about it's hard to tell.